# Impressão de crachá em pvc com impressora térmica

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, impressão

Estou com uma impressora térmica para fazer uns testes de impressão de crachás com cartões de **pvc**.

A princípio montei um modelo de crachá no ***ReportViewer*** e estou gerando ele em **pdf**.
E aparentemente ela está perdendo muita qualidade quando gero nesse formato.

Gostaria de saber **qual a melhorar forma de gerar esse crachá e imprimí-lo com esse tipo de impressora?** Levando em consideração imprimir na forma certa com essa impressora e obter qualidade.

Comment: Talvez usando bitmaps? O consumo de memória vai  ao espaço, eu sei, mas você pode alcançar uma correlação de um pixel na tela para um na impressora se você botar bastante esforço nisso.

Comment: Gerar e renderizar diretamente usando as classes do .NET. Assim você tem mais controle. Porém, pode ser excesso de força bruta... Não sei se é o mais adequado, ou se há uma solução mais elegante. Espero que alguém possa sugerir algo melhor como resposta.

Comment: Tive um problema parecido, pdf realmente foi a melhor solução, mas o ReportViewer não. Parti pro [GMC Inspire](http://www.gmc.net/en/gmc-inspire/gmc-inspire-overview/) e não tive mais problemas.

Comment: Você constata a perda de qualidade quando vê no PDF ou quando imprime?

Comment: A resposta para sua pergunta depende de alguns fatores. Em que parte do processo o crachá está perdendo resolução? Após a impressão todo o conteúdo apresenta aliasing? Ou fontes, etc são impressas em alta resolução, mas recursos visuais como bitmaps não?

Answer (score 1):

Como estou gerando em PDF em um projeto ASP.NET-MVC estou utilizando um método que renderiza o relatório e então o disponibiliza para ser visualizado no browser.

```
public FileContentResult RenderReport(string reportName, List<dynamic> data, string format = "PDF", string deviceInfo = "")
{
    LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport();
    localReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/" + reportName + ".rdlc");

    // Passa os dados para o arquivo .xsd
    ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource(reportName, data);
    localReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);

    format = format.ToUpper();
    string mimeType;
    string encoding;
    string fileNameExtension;

    if (Common.Strings.IsEmpty(deviceInfo))
    {
        deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo>" +
                        "  <OutputFormat>" + format + "</OutputFormat>" +
                        "  <PageWidth>21cm</PageWidth>" +
                        "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +
                        "  <MarginTop>2cm</MarginTop>" +
                        "  <MarginLeft>2cm</MarginLeft>" +
                        "  <MarginRight>2cm</MarginRight>" +
                        "  <MarginBottom>2cm</MarginBottom>" +
                        "</DeviceInfo>";
    }

    Warning[] warnings;
    string[] streams;
    byte[] renderedBytes;

    renderedBytes = localReport.Render(
        format,
        deviceInfo,
        out mimeType,
        out encoding,
        out fileNameExtension,
        out streams,
        out warnings);

    return File(renderedBytes, mimeType);
}
```

O último parâmetro desse método foi adicionado e então passei a setar os valores padrões para o cartão. Pronto. Com isso o cartão/crachá passou a ser gerado com qualidade.